# Linking to a Boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I'm new to the Boost library usage, and I cannot figure out why the following is not working.

I want to compile the following code from the library's documentation:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin) {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As laid out on the documentation, we can use two methods to compile.

**Method 1:** (ok)

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/boost/main.cpp -o main /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.a
```

**Method 2:** (not ok)

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/boost/main.cpp -o main -L/usr/local/lib/ -lboost_regex
```

Using Method 1, everything is fine.
However, using Method 2, when I run the executable I have:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_regex.so.1.75.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Your second command line assumes that a `libboost_regex.so` exists on the path (dynamic linking is the default unless specified otherwise). Because the linker can't find one, it errors.

Comment: Neither of the command lines shown specify a source (e.g. `*.cpp`) file.

Comment: This could help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `/usr/local/lib/` contains both a static library (`libboost_regex.a`) and a shared library (`libboost_regex.so`), if you just specify `-lboost_regex` on your linker command line gcc by default prefers the shared library over the static one. The only way to prevent this is to pass the `-static` flag but this then stops gcc from linking to any shared libraries which may not be what you want. You can also remove the shared libraries from the directory so that gcc can only use the static ones.

To fix the problem at runtime make sure that `/usr/local/lib` is listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` then run `sudo ldconfig` to update the `ldconfig` cache so that the dynamic linker knows where to look for the boost shared libraries at runtime.